# Apache Felix FileInstall won't work

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to setup the FileInstall artifact to my OSGi project but with no success. No bundle is loaded under any folder.

First I run the Felix framework in this location (using the `framework.properties` file or config file):

```
org.osgi.framework.storage=./target/osgi-runner
```

Then I add the FileInstall *dir* property to the framework configuration, like this:

```
felix.fileinstall.dir=./deploy
org.osgi.framework.storage=./target/osgi-runner
```

What the documentation does not say is the relation between the two folders, the `./deploy` folder should be where:

```
|--deploy // here?
|--target
      |--osgi-runner

|--target
      |--osgi-runner
      |--deploy  // here?

|--target
      |--osgi-runner
               |--deploy  //or here?
```

I tell you, I tried all free and none of them work, no bundle is loaded by this `FileInstall` artifact. The artifact uses 2 seconds by default to inspect the folder but it does not matter how much you wait, it simply fails to do its work.

I've been also thinking in developing my own version of this artifact, which is in fact not that complicated, but it would be fine to save some time and effort if I can get this thing working.

Somebody, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I got it finally working. The `/deploy` folder has to be aside the `/osgi-runner`. The problem was that as I was running an Arquillian test with this feature and I was not waiting long enough for the artifact to take action, I was using a timer of 4 seconds so increased it to 10 and it started showing a console message `Using ServiceTracker: Sun Feb 22 12:11:14 2015` indicating that a bundle has been loaded by the service.

I am using the following test case configuration with Arquillian OSGi:

In the `framework.properties` I have:

```
felix.fileinstall.dir=./target/load
```

And the Test-Case implementation is as follows:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterFileCnfTestCase {
    static final String FileInstall = "org.apache.felix.fileinstall-3.4.2.jar";

    @Deployment(name = FileInstall, testable = false)
    public static Archive<?> deploymentD() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(ZipImporter.class, FileInstall)
                       .importFrom(new File("/path/to/apache.felix.fileinstall/" + FileInstall))
                       .as(JavaArchive.class);
    }

    @ArquillianResource
    BundleContext context;

    @Test
    public void fileConfigServices() throws Exception {
        Bundle fiBundle = context.getBundle(FileInstall);
        assertEquals("Bundle ACTIVE", Bundle.ACTIVE, fiBundle.getState());

        String fileName = "/bundle.test-1.0.0.jar";
        String dstFolder = "target/load";
        new File(dstFolder).mkdir();

        File srcBundle = new File("/path/to/bundle.test-1.0.0" + fileName);
        File dstBundle = new File(dstFolder + fileName);

        FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcBundle, dstBundle);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        Bundle bundleTest = context.getBundle(dstBundle.toURI().toString());
        assertNotNull(bundleTest);
    }
}
```